# Does $[G:Z(G)] =n \implies x \mapsto x^{n}$ a group homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $Z(G)$ denote the center of $G$. Its a known result that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is Abelian. So we see that if $|G|/|Z(G)|=p$, where $p$ is a prime, then $G$ becomes an Abelian group and so the map $f: G \to G$ defined by $f(x)=x^{p}$ is a group homomorphism.

Can the question be generalized for any positive integer $n$? That is:

- If $|G|/|Z(G)|=n$, then does it imply that the map $f: G \to G$ defined by $f(x)=x^{n}$ is a group homomorphism??

Comment: What happens when $Z(G) = \{e\}$?

Comment: @AlexZorn Then $f(x) = e$ for all $x$ which is a homomorphism.

Comment: From what you said "is well known" it follows that in fact $\;G/Z(G)\;$ **cannot** be cyclic non-trivial, and thus $\;|G/Z(G)|=p\;$ , with $\;p\;$ a prime, cannot be, and thus the question's basis doesn't really exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's precisely the transfer homomorphism $G \to Z(G)$. This is stated explicitly as Corollary 7.48 in Rotman's book "An Introduction to the Theory of Groups".

Comment: Indeed the transfer homomorphism, yet I highly doubt the OP ever heard of this, and the question itself makes it clear he thought of something else.

Comment: @Timbuc Yes I agree with you entirely! But perhaps it will encourage the OP to learn about the transfer homomorphism. It's not particularly difficult. The whole theory up to Corollary 7.48 takes less than three pages in Rotman's book.

Comment: Well, I'm less optimistic than you about getting the courage to learn something that isn't usually covered in basic group theory when one is flooded with lots of compulsory courses, but I agree with you that it can't hurt. Thanks.